# Can't run Select WPDB to get values between 2 date ranges

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to get rows from a custom table I had created in my wp database.

I am trying to get all records that their date_created time value is in a date range.
This is part of the function I am building

```
global $wpdb;
        $start_date = '2021-07-04';
        $end_date = '2021-10-04';
        $table_name = 'statistics_revenues';
        $query = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}$table_name WHERE DATE(date_created) BETWEEN ($start_date AND $end_date)", ARRAY_A);
        $query_results = $wpdb->get_results($query, ARRAY_A);
```

when I just run a select query with no conditions, everything works, but
as soon as I add the part from "WHERE DATE(date_created)...." the query does not get the needed results.

Where did I get it wrong?

Comment: You have `$start_date = '2021-07-04'`, once you put it into your Query, you loose the quotes which makes it a mathematical expression `2021-07-04` (which equals to `2010`). Thats probably one of the reasons. (Same with `$end_date`)

Answer (score 0):

Remove parenthesis from between just write `BETWEEN $start_date AND $end_date`

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for the bug actually was that I didn't understand the wpdb->prepare method.

It basically works as sprintf and I used it in another manner.
in any case, Thank you everybody :)